# An obvious lemma defined by fun hold on, but can not prove because of recursion

Tags: isabelle

Here, I have defined the regexp expression, and try to prove some obvious lemma, which defined as below.

```
datatype ('v)regexp = ESet | LChr 'v| Concat "'v regexp" "'v regexp"|
                      Alter "('v) regexp" "('v) regexp"| Dot|
                      Star "'v regexp" | Plus "('v) regexp" | Ques "('v) regexp" | \<epsilon>         


fun ConcatRegexp::"'v regexp \<Rightarrow> 'v regexp\<Rightarrow> 'v regexp" where
  "ConcatRegexp r1 r2 = Concat r2 r1"

fun ConcatRegexp2::"'v regexp \<Rightarrow> 'v regexp\<Rightarrow> 'v regexp" where
  "ConcatRegexp2 r1 r2 = Concat (Concat r2 r1) r1"

fun renameDelta1 :: "('v regexp * 'v set * 'v regexp) set \<Rightarrow> ('v regexp => 'v regexp)  \<Rightarrow> ('v regexp *'v set *'v regexp) set" where 
    "renameDelta1 ss f = {(f q,v, f q')| q v q' . (q, v, q')\<in> ss}"

fun renameDelta2 :: "('v regexp * 'v regexp) set \<Rightarrow> ('v regexp => 'v regexp)  \<Rightarrow> ('v regexp  *'v regexp) set" where  
    "renameDelta2 ss f = {(f q, f q')| q q'.(q, q')\<in> ss}"

primrec trans2LTS :: "'v regexp \<Rightarrow> 'v set \<Rightarrow> (('v regexp \<times> 'v set \<times> 'v regexp) set * ('v regexp * 'v regexp) set)" where 
    "trans2LTS (LChr v) alp_set= ({(LChr v,{v},\<epsilon>)},{})"|
    "trans2LTS (ESet) alp_set= ({(ESet,{},\<epsilon>)},{})"|
    "trans2LTS (\<epsilon>) alp_set = ({(\<epsilon>,{},\<epsilon>)},{})"|
    "trans2LTS (Dot) alp_set = ({(Dot ,alp_set, \<epsilon>)},{})"|
    "trans2LTS (Concat r1 r2) alp_set =(renameDelta1 (fst (trans2LTS r1 alp_set)) (ConcatRegexp r2) \<union> (fst (trans2LTS r2 alp_set)),
                                        (renameDelta2 (snd (trans2LTS r1 alp_set)) (ConcatRegexp r2) \<union> {(Concat \<epsilon> r2, r2)}  \<union> snd (trans2LTS r2 alp_set)))"|
    "trans2LTS (Alter r1 r2) alp_set = (fst (trans2LTS r1 alp_set) \<union> fst (trans2LTS r2 alp_set), 
                                        snd (trans2LTS r1 alp_set) \<union> snd (trans2LTS r2 alp_set) \<union> {(Alter r1 r2, r1),(Alter r1 r2, r2)})"|
    "trans2LTS (Star r) alp_set = (renameDelta1 (fst (trans2LTS r alp_set)) (ConcatRegexp (Star r)), 
                                   (renameDelta2 (snd (trans2LTS r alp_set)) (ConcatRegexp (Star r))) \<union> {(Star r, \<epsilon>),(Star r,Concat r (Star r)),(Concat \<epsilon> (Star r), Star r)})"|
    "trans2LTS (Plus r) alp_set = ((renameDelta1 (fst (trans2LTS r alp_set)) (ConcatRegexp2 (Star r))) \<union> (renameDelta1 (fst (trans2LTS r alp_set)) (ConcatRegexp (Star r))), 
                                   {(Plus r, Concat (Concat r (Star r)) (Star r)),(Concat (Concat \<epsilon> (Star r)) (Star r),Concat (Star r) (Star r)),(Concat (Star r) (Star r), \<epsilon>),(Concat (Star r) (Star r), Concat r (Star r)),(Concat \<epsilon> (Star r), Concat (Star r) (Star r))}
                                    \<union>(renameDelta2 (snd (trans2LTS r alp_set)) (ConcatRegexp2 (Star r))) \<union> (renameDelta2 (snd (trans2LTS r alp_set)) (ConcatRegexp (Star r))))"|
    "trans2LTS (Ques r) alp_set = (fst (trans2LTS r alp_set),
                                   {(Ques r,\<epsilon>), (Ques r, r)} \<union> snd (trans2LTS r alp_set))"
```

The lemma called reflexNotHold defined as below:

```
lemma reflexNotHold:"(r, r) ∈ snd (trans2LTS r v) \<Longrightarrow> False"
apply(induction r)
sorry
```

And I first try to prove this lemma by induction. However there are four subgoal that i can not solve, because of the recursive.

I don't know how to prove this lemma, and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you prove the goal by hand? Your problem is *not* the recursion. It is the fact that you need a more complicated argument (my intuition says that `r1 is a subterm of v ==> v \notin trans2TLS r2 v` could work, but I have not thought about it. The key difference between your version talks about ` (r2, r2) ∉ snd (trans2LTS r2 v)`  (IH) and `(Concat r1 r2, Concat r1 r2) ∉ snd (trans2LTS r2 v)` (goal) and it is impossible the IH in the goal directly.)

Comment: Thank you. I prove the goal by regexp cases. The hardest point lies on the Concat regexp, which includes the goal (Concat r1 r2, Concat r1 r2) ∉ snd (trans2LTS r2 v). Back to the definition of trans2LTS, we can see that is r2 = Concat r1 r2, the premise becomes (Concat r1 (Concat r1 r2),Concat r1 (Concat r1 r2)). And this case can not set up. The argument of v here means the alpha set, which has no influence towards the trans2LTS. It's really tricky. :(

Comment: `r2 = Concat r1 r2` is always false. And I don't see how that would follow from your definition from `trans2LTS`

Comment: Because I think that the IH (Concat r1 r2, Concat r1 r2) can be only from the tran2LTS.Concat. In this definition, we define the three possible cases:1:(renameDelta2 (snd (trans2LTS r1 alp_set)) (ConcatRegexp r2) 2：{(Concat \<epsilon> r2, r2)}  3:snd (trans2LTS r2 alp_set)))".  In my opinion, the case one is most possible case to hold on. It concatenate the r2 into trans2LTS r. But in other basic case, there are no case that (r,r) holds on. So that this case is also failed.

Comment: And I agree with you, it need some other arugment here.

Comment: I am at a loss here "In my opinion, the case one is most possible case to hold on": you need to prove this `(Concat r1 r2, Concat r1 r2)` is not in *any* of the cases. You cannot pick one…

Comment: I got your point, my point is that these are all failed, so that (Concat r1 r2, Concat r1 r2) ∉ snd (trans2LTS r2 v). But don't know how to prove it.